# Android: MediaPlayer onPrepared Not Working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service, android-mediaplayer

So I'm attempting to have an audio stream play via the MediaPlayer Class. I was able to play the stream when only it in a Activity. Now I'm trying to have it work via a Service. I added comments to each functions so that I can track what its doing, everything seems to work fine, services get binded and all but now the onPrepared doesn't seems to initiate. I get no error until I try to stop the stream and says was stopped in State 4. I've tried reaching all possible cause and can't seem to find problem. I even build the unprepared within a new MediaPlayer class and still onPrepared doesn't get called. I've only put the service code below since all the other components work.

Any help would be great, Thank you.

Service:

```
public class StreamService extends Service
        implements MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,
        AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener {

    private static final  String TAG = "TESTING";
    private static final  String TAGPlus = "Stream Service - ";

    private static final String ACTION_PLAY = "PLAY";
    private static final String ACTION_PREV = "PREV";
    private static final String ACTION_NEXT = "NEXT";

    public static MediaPlayer streamPlayer;
    ActionPlaying actionPlaying;
    AudioManager audioManager;

    static ServiceState serviceState = StreamService.ServiceState.BLANK;
    private boolean pausedTemporarilyDueToAudioFocus = false;
    private boolean loweredVolumeDueToAudioFocus = false;

    private IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY);
    private BecomingNoisyReceiver myNoisyAudioStreamReceiver = new BecomingNoisyReceiver();

    IBinder mBinder = new MyBinder();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG,TAGPlus+"onBind - "+intent);
        return mBinder;
    }

    public class MyBinder extends Binder{
        public StreamService getService(){
            return StreamService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG,TAGPlus+"onCreate..."+serviceState);

        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

        initNoisyReceiver();
        initMusicPlayer();

    }

    private void initNoisyReceiver() {
        Log.d(TAG,TAGPlus+"initNoisyReceiver..."+serviceState);
        //Handles headphones coming unplugged. cannot be done through a manifest receiver
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
        registerReceiver(myNoisyAudioStreamReceiver, filter);

    }

    public void initMusicPlayer() {
        Log.d(TAG,TAGPlus+"initMusicPlayer - "+serviceState+" - "+streamPlayer);
        if (streamPlayer == null) {
            serviceState = ServiceState.PREPARING;
            streamPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        }

        Log.d(TAG,TAGPlus+"initMusicPlayer - "+serviceState+" - "+streamPlayer);
        streamPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);

        streamPlayer.setAudioAttributes(
                new AudioAttributes
                        .Builder()
                        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                        .build());

        // These are the events that will "wake us up"
        //streamPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this); // player initialized
        streamPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this); // song completed
        streamPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        streamPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);

        //setStreamDataSource();

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        String action = intent.getStringExtra("myActionName");
        Log.d(TAG,TAGPlus+"onStartCommand... - "+action+ "");
        if (action != null) {
            switch (action) {
                case ACTION_PLAY:
                    if(actionPlaying != null)
                    {
                        actionPlaying.playClicked();
                    }
                    break;
                case ACTION_PREV:
                    if(actionPlaying != null)
                    {
                        actionPlaying.prevClicked();
                    }
                    break;
                case ACTION_NEXT:
                    if(actionPlaying != null)
                    {
                        actionPlaying.nextClicked();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
            }
        }

        return START_STICKY;

    }

    public void setStreamDataSource() {
        Log.d(TAG,TAGPlus+"Setting DataSource... - "+streamPlayer+"");
        if (streamPlayer == null) {
            Log.d(TAG,TAGPlus+"MediaPlayer null. Call initMusicPlayer");
            initMusicPlayer();
        }

        //streamPlayer.stop();
        streamPlayer.reset();


        //String url = "http://nap.casthost.net:8800/stream";
        try {
            streamPlayer.setDataSource("http://nap.casthost.net:8800/stream.mp3");
            Log.d(TAG,TAGPlus+"Setting DataSource - Source Assigned...");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException: couldn't start stream");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        streamPlayer.prepareAsync();


    }

    public void playStream() {
        Log.d(TAG,TAGPlus+"playStream... ");
        String url = "http://nap.casthost.net:8800/stream.mp3";
        streamPlayer.reset();

        try {
            streamPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}


        streamPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                Log.d(TAG,TAGPlus+"onPrepared..."+mediaPlayer);
                serviceState = ServiceState.PREPARED;
                streamPlayer.start();
                serviceState = ServiceState.PLAYING;


            }
        });

        streamPlayer.prepareAsync();

    }



    public void startStream() {
        Log.d(TAG,TAGPlus+"startStream... "+serviceState+" - "+streamPlayer);
        if (serviceState != ServiceState.PREPARED)
            setStreamDataSource();


        //startMusicPlayer();
        playStream();

    }

    public void stopStream() {
        Log.d(TAG,TAGPlus+"stopStream... "+serviceState+"");
        serviceState = ServiceState.STOPPED;
        stopMusicPlayer();
    }

    public void startMusicPlayer() {
        Log.d(TAG,TAGPlus+"startMusicPlayer... "+serviceState+"");
        if (serviceState == ServiceState.PLAYING)
            return;

        streamPlayer.start();


    }

    public void stopMusicPlayer() {
        Log.d(TAG,TAGPlus+"stopMusicPlayer..."+streamPlayer);
        if (streamPlayer == null)
            return;

        streamPlayer.stop();
        serviceState = ServiceState.STOPPED;

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        Log.d(TAG,TAGPlus+"onPrepared..."+serviceState+" - "+mediaPlayer);
        serviceState = ServiceState.PREPARED;
        streamPlayer.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        streamPlayer.release();
        streamPlayer = null;


        //cancelNotification();

        if (audioManager != null)
            audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(this);

        stopMusicPlayer();

        unregisterReceiver(myNoisyAudioStreamReceiver);

    }

    public void setCallback(ActionPlaying actionPlaying) {
        Log.d(TAG,TAGPlus+"setCallback...");
        this.actionPlaying = actionPlaying;

    }

    private boolean requestAudioFocus() {
        Log.d(TAG,TAGPlus+"requestAudioFocus... ");

        //Request audio focus for playback
        int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(
                this,
                AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

        //Check if audio focus was granted. If not, stop the service.
        return (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int i) {
        Log.d(TAG,TAGPlus+"onAudioFocusChange..."+i);
        switch (i) {
            // Yay, gained audio focus! Either from losing it for
            // a long or short periods of time.
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:

                if (streamPlayer == null)
                    initMusicPlayer();

                if (pausedTemporarilyDueToAudioFocus) {
                    pausedTemporarilyDueToAudioFocus = false;
                    //unpausePlayer();
                }

                if (loweredVolumeDueToAudioFocus) {
                    loweredVolumeDueToAudioFocus = false;
                    streamPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
                }
                break;

            // Damn, lost the audio focus for a (presumable) long time
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
                //stopMusicPlayer();
                break;

            // Just lost audio focus but will get it back shortly
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:

                if (!isPaused()) {
                    //pausePlayer();
                    pausedTemporarilyDueToAudioFocus = true;
                }
                break;

            // Temporarily lost audio focus but I can keep it playing
            // at a low volume instead of stopping completely
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
                Log.w(TAG, "audiofocus loss transient can duck");

                streamPlayer.setVolume(0.1f, 0.1f);
                loweredVolumeDueToAudioFocus = true;
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        Log.d(TAG,TAGPlus+"onCompletion..."+mediaPlayer);
        serviceState = ServiceState.PLAYING;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
        Log.d(TAG,TAGPlus+"onError...");
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        streamPlayer.reset();
        return false;

    }



    public boolean isPaused() {
        Log.d(TAG,TAGPlus+"isPaused...");
        return serviceState == ServiceState.STOPPED;
    }

    enum ServiceState {
        BLANK,
        PREPARING,
        PREPARED,
        PLAYING,
        STOPPED

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Chris. Good SO question shows an effort in trying to solve the problem. What is correct behavior? What is actual? How one can see it without running your code? What have you done to research the problem?

Comment: Thanks for tip, made some edits to original post.